# .NET - ColorAnimation doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, coloranimation

I created a ColorAnimation for a SpotLight-object, but it doesn't seem to work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
ColorAnimation mouseEnterColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
mouseEnterColorAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
mouseEnterColorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(mouseEnterColorAnimation, "MyAnimatedBrush");

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mouseEnterColorAnimation, new PropertyPath(SpotLightAuditorium.Color));
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
storyboard.Children.Add(mouseEnterColorAnimation);
storyboard.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Storyboard.SetTargetName`, the name must be the value of the actual [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) property of the FrameworkElement instance where you want to animate a property. So in your case probably an instance of the `SpotLightAuditorium` control:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(mouseEnterColorAnimation, mySpotlightAuditorium.Name);
```

The propertypath must be a reference to an actual dependency property:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mouseEnterColorAnimation, new PropertyPath(SpotLightAuditorium.ColorProperty));
```

If you want to animate a Brush directly (wich doesn't have a Name property) you have to register the name of the brush in the current Page/UserControl/Window using [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) This the same as using XAML `x:Name`.

ALternativlely you can use the following approach for elements that derive from [Animatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.animation.animatable.aspx):

```
ColorAnimation mouseEnterColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
mouseEnterColorAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
mouseEnterColorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
myAnimatedBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, null); // remove the old animation to prevent memoryleak
myAnimatedBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, mouseEnterColorAnimation);
```

Comment: SpotlightAuditorium is a concrete instance of Spotlight which doesn't seem to have a Name-attribute.

Also I don't get what you mean with SpotLightAuditorium.ColorProperty.

Comment: I was assuming that your SpotLightAuditorium would get a Color dependency property, wich you would then use for animation. If Spotlight doesn't have a name property you will have to use the RegisterName method as described in my answer to set the name.

Comment: How do I set a Color dependency property?

I also don't understand why I need a brush instead of a regular color (as SpotLight (3D-Light)) only has a color-attribute.

Sorry for asking that much.

Comment: Ah - we are talking *System.Windows.Media.Media3D.SpotLight* here. This class has a Color dependency property. You would use it for animation (no Brush invloved- `"MyAnimatedBrush"` made me aussume that you *might* have a brush somewhere. So you would call RegsiterName for the Spotlight, and then  `Storyboard.SetTargetName(mouseEnterColorAnimation, mySpotlightAuditorium.Name)` and then `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mouseEnterColorAnimation, new PropertyPath(SpotLight.ColorProperty));`

Comment: YAY! It finally works.
Why doesn't SetTarget instead of SetTargetName work?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register the brush's name with the page so that it can be targeted by storyboards:

```
SolidColorBrush myAnimatedBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
myAnimatedBrush.Color = ?? choose a color

this.RegisterName("MyAnimatedBrush", myAnimatedBrush);
```